# Extract the part enclosed by a predefined multiline character sequence 

Tags: perl, awk, grep, nawk

Hope the AWK gurus can provide a solution to my problem .

I have a file that goes like this :

```
cat cat cat cat cat cat dog rat ate dog tit 
dog cat dog dog dog rat dog pat ate cat dog
```

I have to use AWK to extract the pattern between the first occuring **c** and a  **d** .Starting from the first **c** a count should be kept on the number of **c**'s and **d**'s such that when the count matches , the part between the first **c** and the matched **d** shoud be ouput to a file including the number of the line in which the match for **d** occured .

In this particular example the match occurs on the seventh dog , therefore the output will have to be :

```
cat cat cat cat cat cat dog rat ate dog tit 
dog cat dog dog dog rat d
```

The match can go beyond just two lines ! *The output can or cannot be inclusive of the **c** and the **d*** .There exists all kinds of characters inclusive of the special ones in the text ! 
In order for the print to occur the count has to be matched .

Thanks in advance for the replies. Suggestions are always welcome .

EDIT : The capture of the pattern between **c** and **d** can be compromised as long as the condition is met and the line number of the exit **d** is obtained :)

Comment: did you want to tag this as homework? Good luck.

Comment: The idea behind the algorithm is complex ! I just explained it in simple words ,that is why it seems like a kid's home work ! This is just a petite partie of a large one ! My awk skills are not very good . I  started with O'reilly 's Sed and Awk yesterday ! So might take a little to implement this one .btw I work and not at home ! Wait a few days or may be hours and if no one has a solution yet ,I would have done it by then ! Good day mate !

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  Show us your code, and we'll help you debug.

Comment: @ghoti - In transit now ! Will update my progress today if am not over drunk !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few tips, without giving the full solution:

By default, awk considers each line as a record. The default record separator is `RS="\n"`.

Depending on your version of awk, you may be able to set `RS`, the record separator, to a regex which matches either `c` or `d`. Then, for each record, you can check the `RT` variable, which will contain either `c` or `d`, depending on what has **actually** been matched. Starting from there, using a variable incremented on `c`, decremented on `d` you will be able to find the end of the match when it reaches 0.

You can then use a variable that contains your match so far, and keep concatenating `RT` and the new record to it, until you're done.

If you need to know the line number of the end of the match, you can set `RS` to a regex that either matches `c`, `d`, as previously, but also add the possibility to match `\n`. And by maintaining another counter variable incremented every time `RT` tells you that `\n` has been matched, you'll have your line number.

Comment: **+1** for providing just as much code as the OP included in the question.  :-)

Comment: **+1**  for giving a head start :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` solution just for fun:

```
sed -rne ':r;$!{N;br};s/^[^c]*(.*d)[^d]*$/\1/;:a;h;s/[^cd]//g;' \
-e ':s;s/d(.*)c/c\1d/;ts;s/cd/c\nd/;T;y/c/d/;/^(d+)\n\1$/{g;i -------' \
-e 'p};g;s/d[^d]*d$/d/;ta'
```

This prints all satisfying sequences from longest to shortest.

Comment: Genuinely appreciate your enthusiasm mate :)